# Foreign national drawing up a will in the US

Tags: wills

My wife is a German she wants to draw up a will in the US. Will it be valid in Germany and Canada?

Comment: It really isn't clear... Is she a German citizen residing in the US? What does Germany and Canada have to do with it? It would help if you explained where her citizenship is, where she resides, where the property is that she is covering in the will, and probably the nationality of the heirs.

Comment: Probably. There are special formalities for an international will that can be followed to increase the likelihood of that, but even if those weren't followed it would probably be honored.

Answer (score 2):

If done properly, Germany and Canada will recognize the Will executed in the United States.

There is a treaty that mandates that "international wills" be recognized if special procedures for their execution are followed.

In Colorado, where I practice, these procedures are set forth in the state's probate code, which is its local version of the Uniform International Wills Act which most states adopt in order to implement the treaty. It is set forth a [Colorado Revised Statutes Sections 15-10-1101 to 15-10-1110](https://leg.colorado.gov/sites/default/files/images/olls/crs2016-title-15.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

See a lawyer, an expert in trans-national probate law.

In general, a will made correctly under US law will be valid in the US regardless of the citizenship of the testator. However, if you are dealing with cross-national property issues and/or benificiaries then you need good legal advice.